# Why local git repo is asking for email?

Tags: git

I understand why `Git` would want to know your data if you try to push / pull to remote branch. But if I want to have local repo that would exist only on my laptop, why would it want me to provide my credentials before committing to it?

```
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"
```

Comment: How would git know who did commits if it doesn’t know who you are? There’s no difference between locals and remotes and whatnots.

Comment: But why would it need to know it if everything is stored on my laptop?

Comment: It’s the same as why you need an account on your laptop OS if it’s just you. As I said, it needs to know who did things. The repo is exactly the same wether it’s on your laptop or on the moon. There’s no difference and every single commit and action needs information about who did it.

Comment: Well..... not certainly _every_ action. But **commit**? That _certainly_ needs to know user/enail to set committer/author for the revision (**and**, by the way, those are **not** related to pushing/pulling).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because the author and committer identity is a mandatory component of every GIT commit file.   As you can see in the following sources:

- [Git Objects](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects)

  > The format for a commit object is simple: it specifies the top-level tree for the snapshot of the project at that point; the parent commits if any (the commit object described above does not have any parents); the author/committer information (which uses your user.name and user.email configuration settings and a timestamp); a blank line, and then the commit message.
- [Git File format](https://www.samba.org/%7Ejelmer/dulwich/docs/tutorial/file-format.html)

  > A commit file looks like this:

  ```
  commit <content length><NUL>tree <tree sha>
  parent <parent sha>
  [parent <parent sha> if several parents from merges]
  author <author name> <author e-mail> <timestamp> <timezone>
  committer <author name> <author e-mail> <timestamp> <timezone>

  <commit message>
  ```

If you don't tell Git who you are, it cannot create well-formed commit files.  So ... it insists that you tell it.

There is nothing stopping you from using fake identity information in your local repository, but it is liable to come back and bite you if you later need to publish the commits that you made.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is your identity, or it specifies the identity of a person who works in a repo.
Imagine that two person work on a same system for some reasons. So everybody can works in his or her own repo with different identity.

Answer (score 0):

Git commits have metadata associated with them like the time. The author of the commit (their name) and the authors email are part of that metadata. You could stub these as empty strings or bogus values if it's purely a project you're doing locally but it's pretty important information in a collaborative environment for things like `blame` (who wrote what and when).

From: https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Internals-Git-Objects

> [...] author/committer information (which uses your user.name and user.email
> configuration settings [...]

Answer (score 0):

It's common mistake to think that this email is your credential but it's in fact just an information used when git create commits.

The proof is that you could put whatever wrong or no-reply email even if it could be a bad idea.

The real secure way to ensure that someone created a specific commit is to sign it.

And your credentials are used only for connecting to the remote server to fetch/push your commits.

Answer (score 0):

Every commit stores (permanently and unchangeably, for as long as the commit itself continues to exist) a name-and-email-address pair—or more precisely, two such pairs—as "author" and "committer", along with two date-and-time stamps.  Git needs to get these from somewhere.  The traditional place from which Git has always gotten these two strings are the `user.name` and `user.email` settings.

Git *can* be *compiled* to use OS-level information, if present, to provide the name and email address *if* they're not in a Git configuration file.  When Git is compiled this way, if `user.name` and/or `user.email` are not set, Git will use the compiled-in OS-dependent code to do this.  However, there's *another* setting, `user.useConfigOnly`, to *disable* this mode.  [The `git config` documentation](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config) describes this as follows:

> `user.useConfigOnly`
>       Instruct Git to avoid trying to guess defaults for `user.email` and
> `user.name,` and instead retrieve the values only from the
> configuration. For example, if you have multiple email addresses
> and would like to use a different one for each repository, then
> with this configuration option set to true in the global config
> along with a name, Git will prompt you to set up an email before
> making new commits in a newly cloned repository. Defaults to `false`.

Presumably your Git is compiled without the guessing code or you have `user.useConfigOnly` set to `true` (or perhaps both).

(As others have noted, these two settings are not used for authentication.  I think this might have been clearer had the names of the configuration items been different, e.g., `commit.callme` and `commit.emailme` or some such.  But the `user.*` settings were chosen decades ago; we're stuck with those spellings now.)